# Tracking the hours submitted to work items by users in TFS

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, tfs, scrum

I want to get the hours I have submitted to work items in TFS programatically. How can I do that?

For example if I add 4 hours to User Story 2222 and Task 1111, I want to be able to extract the hours, userstory number and task number. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start by looking at the [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.aspx) and specifically at the [WorkItemCollection Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.workitemcollection.aspx).

You can query for a collection of work items:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection"));
WorkItemStore workItemStore = (WorkItemStore)tpc.GetService(typeof(WorkItemStore)); 
WorkItemCollection queryResults = workItemStore.Query("
   Select [State], [Title] 
   From WorkItems
   Where [Work Item Type] = 'User Story'
   Order By [State] Asc, [Changed Date] Desc");
```

or get a specific WorkItem by ID:

```
WorkItem workItem = workItemStore.GetWorkItem(62);
```

After you have a specific work item (or a collection of them) and the *hours* field's name, you can do: WorkItem["field-name"] or WorkItem.Fields["field-name"].Value to get/set the value of the field.